# How to filter game apps from installed apps on device programmatically

Tags: android

I want to filter game application from installed apps in my device. My Question is:

Is it possible to filter game applications from all installed apps? If the answer is yes, please provide some methods or tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. There is no reliable metadata which identifies an app as game or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to filter games in or out?

There's no way to positively identify whether an app was downloaded from one of the Game categories in the Play Store (short of doing some server database lookup), but there are a number of clues you can look for in the app that may identify it as a game:

1) Check for use of Google Play Games Services, by checking for the existence of the appropriate meta-data:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

You can get hold of this using `PackageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, GET_META_DATA)`

2) See if the app is using a game engine, by examining the files contained in its apk file, looking for things such as:

- the Unity engine
- Adobe AIR runtime

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way of doing this, because for the android system, all the apps are similar with its own set of resources and java classes.
There are games of various sizes starting from few KB to a large sized several MB. Also there are utility apps that are in various sized.
So its not practically possible to identify as there isn't any specific keyword unique for games.
So you can't achieve this by any means.

Answer (score 0):

there is a one way to find category of installed application from your own application programmatically,
In this way you hit an API with two required param one is package name and second is access token key which allow you sign in at https://data.42matters.com/launchpad and then you hit Api
documentation of Api is https://data.42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/lookup
hope you find your solution 
thank you